# How to model my database for a one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I am learning backend development in Django and came across this problem.

Say I am designing a travel app:
I have two databases **USER** and **TRIP** with one-to-many relationship. i.e., each user can have *multiple trips* and each trip can be taken by only one *user*.

**TRIP** has a column ***trip-number***. I would like to auto-increment this column for every row added into the **TRIP** database **BUT** the increment should be independent for each user starting from 1

TRIP table

| user | trip-number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

Something like that? I cannot auto-increment the whole column as it has to be unique for each trip taken by the user BUT the numbers can be same across different users.

Ideally I prefer to do this automatically on the server-end (sql) instead of writing a logic in the client. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You can create trigger on insert/delete for it and find the max number for each user and add one to it for newly added record. But I would not suggest to use trigger. Instead you can create one view, which will have one extra column for trip_number..

Comment: That's what I am doing right now. For each insertion, I am filtering and getting the number of trips for a user and incrementing it. But I wanted to see if there's a better way to do this and also I am not missing anything obvious. What do you mean by the second part of your statement? This table has other columns such as source, destination etc., Pulling out trip_number column alone and making it a separate table doesn't have any meaning associated to it right?

Comment: Don't do this. Just store an AI.

Answer (score 1):

Using `trigger` to update the `trip_num` column is one way to achieve the desired result but I would suggest not to use the `triggers` as it has many disadvantages. Few of them are as follows:

- you will need trigger for insert/delete/update actions.
- In `insert trigger`, you will have to assign `trip_number` per user.
- In `update trigger`, you will have to check if user column is updated, if yes then you will have to arrange `trip_number` accordingly.
- In `delete trigger`, you will have to arrange all the `trip_num`, if one of the record except last record of the user is deleted.
- If two transactions occur at the same time for same the user then there will chances that triggers assign the same `trip_num` to different rows of the same user.

So, to avoid it, you can use the `view` as follows:

```
Create view vw_name as
Select t.*, -- use column names and remove trip_num column 
       Row_number() over (partition by user order by trip_date) as trip_num
  From your_table t
```